# Patch binary while documenting original at the same time in Ghidra

Tags: ghidra, patching

I'm starting work on a simultaneous documentation and patching project on a single binary. Some of the code to be documented will also be overwritten by the patch, but most of it won't, so I need a workflow that lets me access and document both versions at once. Is there a more efficient way to do this than just manually changing both files?